# How to pass a reactive prop to child in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I creating a reusable modal in which I want to pass the prop `:loading="loading"`. But as of now the `loading` property initialized in data is not reactive. How can I update loading in the parent so it is reactive inside the child component ?

Parent component template:

```
<child_component :loading="loading"></child_component>
```

Parent component script:

```
     data() {
            return {
                loading: false
            }
        },

          onDelete() {
                this.loading = true;
                setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
                this.loading = false;
            },
```

child :

```
       <v-btn icon
           :loading="loading"
            <v-icon>{{icon}}</v-icon>
       </v-btn>

        ...

props: { disabled: { Boolean, default: false } }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Move `this.loading = false;` inside `setTimeout` and use arrow function as i have used below else you will not get reference to `this`.

```
onDelete() {
  this.loading = true;
  setTimeout(() => { this.loading = false; }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Eww, no. This is not how things should be done.